# MS Access Query Sort with Percents: Why sort only by first digit?

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, percentage

I have the following query (which runs great) that pulls ID, week ending date, performance, and overtime.

```
SELECT 
d2s_roster_tbl.employee_id, 
Format([WEEK_ENDING_DT],"mm/dd") AS week,
IIf([d2s_performance_tbl].[hrs_worked]=0,"",IIf([d2s_roster_tbl.position_desc] Like
    "*selector*",FormatPercent(Round(([d2s_performance_tbl].[goal_hrs]/[d2s_performance_tbl].[hrs_worked]),2),0) & 
    [d2s_performance_tbl].[lift_flag],IIf([d2s_roster_tbl.position_desc] Like
    "*operator*",FormatPercent(Round(([d2s_performance_tbl].[goal_hrs]/[d2s_performance_tbl].[hrs_worked]),2),0),""))) AS Perf,
d2s_performance_tbl.OT

FROM 
d2s_roster_tbl 
INNER JOIN d2s_performance_tbl ON D2s_roster_tbl.employee_id = d2s_performance_tbl.employee_id;
```

When I sort by OT, it sorts properly.  When I sort by perf (the calculated percentage) it appears to only sort by the first digit--a descending sort shows results like this:

```
6%
52%
500%
475%
47%
4%
39%
30%
23%
220%
199%
19%
188%
```

What could be causing it to sort like this?  All numeric fields in the d2s_performance_tbl have 2 decimal places with the following formats:

```
Field Size: Double
Format: General Number
Decimal Places: Auto
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that this is caused by the `FormatPercent` function which from what I understand and can only be logical is that it converts to a string.  The only way you can have a '%' in a values is if it is a string.  This is what's causing your sort to be off. Remove the `FormatPercent` and see what happens.

If you want the formatted value you could add another column to your output as the format and sort on the calculated that is not formatted to get your formatted column in the correct order.

Comment: This does answer my specified question, but does not help my end goal with the report.  This resultset goes into a crosstab query, which in turn goes into a Master Query, on which my report is based.  I'll try including the "dummy" performance data through the crosstab and Master Query and see what happens.  I have a form that lets the user sort (asc or desc) by any of the fields. I'm thinking I can include both values in the Master Query, show only the formatted in the report, then call on the original to sort.  Access won't let me change the format of the fields from the report properties

Comment: @TrevorD Glad you can try to work something out. Unfortunately Access has many pitfalls and should probably be scrapped altogether as a DB, but I understand sometimes it isn't an option especially for those who want something cheap and to be able to get up and running fast.